Difference between 2 years in area (ha) within each condition rating
I've got some condition data for hundreds of parcels of land. I've collected this twice now (2017 and 2023). I've previously compared the count of parcels that fall into each condition category (poor, fair, good, very good) in 2017 and 2023 using an exact marginal homogeneity test for ordered data in r.




Very good (2023)
Good (2023)
Fair (2023)
Poor (2023)




Very good (2017)
2
5
2
1


Good (2017)
2
79
39
4


Fair (2017)
2
18
65
6


Poor (2017)
0
0
4
2



mh_test(as.table(result_table), scores = list(response = 1:length(score)), distribution='exact')

I'd like to now compare the area that falls into each condition category between the two years. Would an exact marginal homogeneity test using area be appropriate or should this only be used for count data?

If your area values are integers (and they can always be by rescaling your units), then your areas are count data (number of $m^2$, or sq-ft, etc.). But... there may be a more interesting analysis to perform:  you have an outcome variable (parcel condition), and 2 variables (time, and area). You could try an ordinal logistic regression, to predict condition as a function of time and area... (and maybe other variables you collected)
